# Utilizing Google's template user feedback form

Tags: android, email, feedback, system-information

I'd like to build a feedback page. I noticed that all google apps use the same one, and that in Android L the UI for these pages is being overriden by the OS to have a grey action bar with no version number in title. This makes me wonder if there is a component of Android I can point the feedback button to that opens a native feedback page within my app with: text field, email selection, device data dump, and send button.

[image: Google's Feedback Page in L][image: email sent from spinner menu]